# Updation of Dictionary Key Values which are in JSON array / ArrayLIst C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, arraylist

Need to update `ArrayList` `arlData` with same data shown below but need to remove `albumName` values except top 1 i.e. `albumName[0]`´s value, Json data should update as shown in output below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /*Declaration */
    ArrayList arlData = null;
    arlData = new ArrayList();
    Dictionary<string, object> data = null;

    //Json data format
    string json = @"{""Id"":""1"",""Count"":""2"",""musicName"":""test1"",""albumName"":[""1"", ""2"",""3""]}"
          ,json2 = @"{""Id"":""2"",""Count"":""1"",""musicName"":""test2"",""albumName"":[""4"", ""5""]}"
          ,json3 = @"{""Id"":""3"",""Count"":""1"",""musicName"":""test3"",""albumName"":[""6"", ""7""]}";

    /*Adding data to array list   */
    arlData.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json));
    arlData.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json2));
    arlData.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json3));
    int intbytlen = 0;

    if (arlData.Count > 0)        
    {
        intbytlen = arlData.Count;                
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < intbytlen; iterator++)
        {
            //Data fetch
            data = (Dictionary<string, object>)arlData[iterator];

            //Data serialization
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
{"Id":"1","Count":"2","musicName":"test1","albumName":["1"]}
{"Id":"2","Count":"1","musicName":"test2","albumName":["4"]}
{"Id":"3","Count":"1","musicName":"test3","albumName":["6"]}
```

Comment: I would consider using a library to build your JSON. Newtonsoft, in my opinion is one the best. I would also create an object that represents your json strings and serialise/ de-serialise as needed, you could then easily make changes to the objects.

Comment: can you please brief on creating object and do update on the de-serialise value & I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` library

Comment: Sure, you would create your models (classes) and the albumName property would return a List<int>. Then when you need to make changes you would de-serialise your objects, access the List<int> and remove all items apart from index 0. Then serialise again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simplest way, without creating class & properties to update dictionary key values and JSON data, just used `type dynamic` to fetch data from array list!

```
if (data.ContainsKey("albumName") && data["albumName"] != null)
 {
   //Assign specific data to type dynamic by deserialising the data
   dynamic arryAlbumName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data["albumName"].ToString());
   if (arryAlbumName != null && arryAlbumName.Count > 0)
   {
    for (int count = 0; count < arryAlbumName.Count; count++)
    {
      if (count == 0)
      {
        ArrayList albumName = new ArrayList();
        //Check for data exists and update the array value to arlData[]
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arryAlbumName[count].ToString()))
        {
            albumName.Add(arryAlbumName[count]);
            data.Remove("albumName");
            data.Add("albumName", albumName);
            arlData[iterator] = data;
         }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
```

The output is

```
 {"Id":"1","Count":"2","musicName":"test1","albumName":["1"]}
 {"Id":"2","Count":"1","musicName":"test2","albumName":["4"]}
 {"Id":"3","Count":"1","musicName":"test3","albumName":["6"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a model similar to this.

```
public class AlbumList
{      
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string MusicName { get; set; }
    public List<Album> AlbumName { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int AlbumName { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiating and fill objects with data, and add to a `List<AlbumList>`. You can then use Newtonsoft to serialise and deserialise when needed.

```
var albums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AlbumList>>(json);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(albums, Formatting.Indented);
```

Once deserialised, access the `List<AlbumList>` and remove all items that aren't index 0.

```
for (int i = 1; i < AlbumList.Count; i++)
            {
                AlbumList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
```